# jQuery - OnClick listener triggered after 1 second on phone

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I'm writing a cordova app and testing it on my phone, a Wiko FEVER. 
I'm registering the onClick listener using jQuery doing this:

```
$("#massages").on('click', function() {
                $("#massagesSousCat").show();
            });
```

When I'm testing with cordova run on my phone, I have to wait approx. 1 second after I clicked the item for the event to be triggered. When I launch my app with cordova simulate, it works well (cordova simulate sends the webview in Chrome)

I don't know what's causing it and some help would be welcome !

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Try either adding the following to your `<head></head>` tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

Or add this to your styles:

```
html {
    touch-action: manipulation;
}
```

(Source: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2013/12/300ms-tap-delay-gone-away)

Comment: Nothing changed. I already had the viewport meta, added the html css, and tried to remove the other parameters of the viewport meta. Thanks for the link, I even tried to listen to the touchend event but I still have the lag. Any clue ?

Comment: Also tried to listen to touch and touchstrat, same result.

Comment: Hmm, no more ideas on my end then :\

Comment: Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

It can come from delay between click & event triggering.

Try to add [fastClick library](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick) in your project !

P.S. : don't forgot to load it via `FastClick.attach(document.body);`

Comment: I did include fastclick, attached it with ```$(function() {
                FastClick.attach(document.body);
            });``` , the Fastclick.attach() method is called (I checked that with debuggin), but the issue is still here. Any clue ?

Comment: Hmm... It may come from your android version (if it's an old version)

Comment: Could be this... I'll investigate ^^

Comment: keep us informed !